# Wordpress search query, how to modify the sql

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, sql

I have a problem with the query search, which means I would only look for posts with post_status = published. The problem is that after adding my conditions, wordpress writes an "OR wp_terms.name LIKE% s% that cancels all my previous conditions. How can I remove this instruction or change the OR in AND.

I have already tried various solutions including posts_where but the condition "wp_terms.name LIKE% s% always remains.

I added this condition to the function.php file of my wordpress template to filter the search.

function.php

```
function nameFunction($query){
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        if ($query->is_search()) {

            $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish');
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'lp_course');
            $query->set('s', get_search_query());
            $query->set('order', 'desc' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'nameFunction');
```

This is the generate query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}cantieri{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}cantieri{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}cantieri{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}'))) AND (wp_posts.post_password = '') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'lp_course' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%cantieri%' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}cantieri{49d63a129bd514e58a4ec329ce90100d6896c431356d4f358f3b347caaecea35}' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is the part that I think gives problems:

```
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'lp_course' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%cantieri%'
```

I would like to remove the final condition or change it with AND.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What URL are you accessing the search through? I doubt that WordPress randomly adds a search for a specific term called `cantieri`. Have you deactivated all plugins and switched to a default theme to make sure there is no other code interfering?

Comment: This is the url that is generated: "http://education.centrosoftware.com/?s=cantieri". the query would also be correct since I tell him to look for the word "cantieri" but I don't want this condition to go over the others.

Comment: Ok. And as for my other question: Did you disable other plugins and check again? I don't think searching over `wp_terms` is the default (but I can't check right now)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Now I'll try! Thanks

Comment: I tried to disable all the plugins but nothing changes :(